# How do you switch a jQuery function call (change actions)

Tags: jquery, function

I've seen this done, but I can't find an example anymore. What I'd like is to switch a  jQuery action... the code below is just an example, it is not the code I am using, I'm just trying to remember how this works.

```
var action = (getURL) ? "attr('href')" : "html()";
alert( "The result is" + $('#myLink')[action] );
```

I also tried

```
var action = (getURL) ? ".attr('href')" : ".html()";
alert( "The result is" + $('#myLink')[action] );
```

sorry my memory stinks and I couldn't find an example of this in the jQuery docs either. I'm not even sure if those are called "actions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to switch the function call?

Given that approach, you probably need two separate variables:

```
var action = (getURL) ? "attr" : "html";
var param = (getURL) ? 'href' : null;
alert( "The result is" + $('#myLink')[action](param));
```

But why not use an if statement like normal?

```
if (getURL)
    alert("The result is" + $('#myLink').attr('href'));
else
    alert("The result is" + $('#myLink').html());
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was trying to get... function call, LOL ok I'll edit the title :P

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason you don't want to do this?

```
var result = '';
if (getURL) {
    result = $('#myLink').attr('href');
} else {
    result = $('#myLink').html();
}
alert("The result is " + result);
```

Or, how about:

```
var result = getURL ? $('#myLink').attr('href') : $('#myLink').html();
alert("The result is " + result);
```

Comment: Well, I'm working on a jQuery plugin. And I want the user to be able to tell the script where to get some data, be it from an attribute of an element or inside a tag. It might not be the best way, but I'm tinkering and learning.

Answer (score 1):

The way to call a function when you won't know the parameter list until run time is by using `apply()`.

```
var action = getUrl ? "attr" : "html";
var params = getUrl ? ['href'], [];

var $e = $('#myLink');
$e[action].apply($e.get(0), params);
```

The first parameter to `apply` is the object which will become `this` inside the function.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could do this

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
alert( "The result is" + ((getURL) ? $('#myLink').attr('href') : $('#myLink').html()) );
```